# Java: call OS for administrator level authentication?

Tags: java, authentication, database-design, operating-system, password-protection

I'm making a mock inventory program for an inventory database, and I want to implement a feature where if in a use case scenario, a warehouse receiver (who wouldn't have administrator login status in the company network I would hope) would attempt to delete a record of the database, he would have to enter OS level administrator authentication since deletion of records could wreak tax audit havoc. I want to make the deletion still accessible if the real person in the office next door could access the software if the receiver informs his supervisor that he's made a critical mistake in data entry such as UPC. The supervisor could then inform her network admin...

So with that said, I'm wondering how I call the operating system. Since I've never done this before the first thing that came to mind was something like

```
String adminPassword = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                       "Enter Network Administrator Password");

if(callSomeOSFeatureForAdminPasswordReturnsTrue(adminPassword)){ 
    record.delete();
}
```

Sorry if this is a dumb question but I've never done anything like this and it doesn't make sense from a security standpoint because then what's to prevent a rather dark-minded programmer from transmitting that String? That's kind of a tangent but basically I just would like to know what I should look up to make sure end user local network administrator level authentication is done on a database record deletion attempt. Every year warehouses have to audit everything in the inventory so if some receiver thought "delete" was supposed to be used every time you ran out of a product temporarily the audit would be a nightmare (Trust me, I've been through these in real life and they're like a tornado through the warehouse, and if more than only a tiny amount of things are unaccounted for, the supervisors are BEYOND mad.)

Comment: it's really doesn't make sense.

Comment: I know - hence the inquiry. Can a java program ensure that only a user with administrator privileges of the end users network can utilize a specific delete() method within a program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not something that will be built into Java - it runs in a virtual machine, (mostly) independent of the actual Operating System. You have to rely on calling some program on the machine that will answer a question like that. This is dependant on the actual OS that is running, so it will not be cross-platform. Also you should not be asking for a password and then sending it forward.

But you should not be doing this anyway - privileges in a database should be related to the database users - not to whether the user is an admin on his computer. So you should rethink the security there.

Comment: It's not a real database it's just a mock database for a semester long project in college which I'm writing the UML for. The requirements state there must be a "delete" feature in the mock database, but at the same time, our Business Software Systems teacher last semester was saying you should never delete records from a database, so I'm trying to merge that with this project requirement even tho its asking me to explicitly allow someone to delete a mock record. Maybe I don't need to go into that much detail for the scope of the project, but like most projects, we're left in the dark

Comment: But that pretty much gives an explanation and answers the question as "no, you can't do that with Java" so I'll take that as an answer and just either set the record to be hidden behind the scenes or do something else

Comment: Well the answer is both "not really a Java thing" and "you should not rely on that as a security measure". The point the your teacher was maybe making is that you should just mark a record as unused or something like that. And you can actually make UML actors etc that have different roles, so that you have people that can make new items in the database, but only a senior user can delete them.